# Slider on my PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

I want my preference menu to have something to change the duration of a vibration.

There is no `slider` tag for prefs.xml, so what is the best way to do this?

Comment: This seems to be quite nice http://robobunny.com/wp/2011/08/13/android-seekbar-preference/

Comment: Check out my inline (no dialog) SeekBarPreference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012305/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-seekbar-to-my-actual-preference-screen/30236143#30236143

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could create your own Preference class that extends [DialogPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html) and shows a [SeekBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) as the dialog view.

Comment: Using a dialog is not always the best alternative, what if you have several sliders and want to see them next to each other?

Comment: Is there no way to put a slider directly on the screen?

Comment: @mattblang the author of this library https://github.com/jayschwa/AndroidSliderPreference IMO has a point when enumerating the disadvantages of putting it directly on the screen:
- Higher chance of accidental clicks
- No way to confirm or cancel potential changes

Answer (score 40):

I improved the link provided by Macarse, so that the value is saved only on ok button click, and so that you can use `@string/...` values in the XML file.

Here is the code:

```
/* The following code was written by Matthew Wiggins 
 * and is released under the APACHE 2.0 license 
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Improvements :
 * - save the value on positive button click, not on seekbar change
 * - handle @string/... values in xml file
 */

package fr.atcm.carpooling.views.utils;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SeekBarPreference extends DialogPreference implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnClickListener
{
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private attributes :
    private static final String androidns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private TextView mSplashText,mValueText;
    private Context mContext;

    private String mDialogMessage, mSuffix;
    private int mDefault, mMax, mValue = 0;
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor :
    public SeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context,attrs); 
        mContext = context;

        // Get string value for dialogMessage :
        int mDialogMessageId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(androidns, "dialogMessage", 0);
        if(mDialogMessageId == 0) mDialogMessage = attrs.getAttributeValue(androidns, "dialogMessage");
        else mDialogMessage = mContext.getString(mDialogMessageId);

        // Get string value for suffix (text attribute in xml file) :
        int mSuffixId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(androidns, "text", 0);
        if(mSuffixId == 0) mSuffix = attrs.getAttributeValue(androidns, "text");
        else mSuffix = mContext.getString(mSuffixId);

        // Get default and max seekbar values :
        mDefault = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(androidns, "defaultValue", 0);
        mMax = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(androidns, "max", 100);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // DialogPreference methods :
    @Override 
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(6,6,6,6);

        mSplashText = new TextView(mContext);
        mSplashText.setPadding(30, 10, 30, 10);
        if (mDialogMessage != null)
            mSplashText.setText(mDialogMessage);
        layout.addView(mSplashText);

        mValueText = new TextView(mContext);
        mValueText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mValueText.setTextSize(32);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.addView(mValueText, params);

        mSeekBar = new SeekBar(mContext);
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        layout.addView(mSeekBar, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        if (shouldPersist())
            mValue = getPersistedInt(mDefault);

        mSeekBar.setMax(mMax);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mValue);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        mSeekBar.setMax(mMax);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mValue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restore, Object defaultValue)  
    {
        super.onSetInitialValue(restore, defaultValue);
        if (restore) 
            mValue = shouldPersist() ? getPersistedInt(mDefault) : 0;
            else 
                mValue = (Integer)defaultValue;
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // OnSeekBarChangeListener methods :
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek, int value, boolean fromTouch)
    {
        String t = String.valueOf(value);
        mValueText.setText(mSuffix == null ? t : t.concat(" " + mSuffix));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek) {}
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek) {}

    public void setMax(int max) { mMax = max; }
    public int getMax() { return mMax; }

    public void setProgress(int progress) { 
        mValue = progress;
        if (mSeekBar != null)
            mSeekBar.setProgress(progress); 
    }
    public int getProgress() { return mValue; }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Set the positive button listener and onClick action : 
    @Override
    public void showDialog(Bundle state) {

        super.showDialog(state);

        Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (shouldPersist()) {

            mValue = mSeekBar.getProgress();
            persistInt(mSeekBar.getProgress());
            callChangeListener(Integer.valueOf(mSeekBar.getProgress()));
        }

        ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).dismiss();
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

EDIT :

Here is a screenshot :

[image: Screenshot SeekBarPreference]

EDIT : on arlomedia's demand, here are all the needed pieces of code (I just recreated a new projet, it is perfectly working. I corrected some bugs in SeekBarPreference class, so don't forget to re-copy/paste it) :

MainActivity :

```
package fr.at.testsliderpref;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.menu_settings : {

                startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));

                break;
            }
        }

        return true;    
    }
}
```

SettingsActivity :

```
package fr.at.testsliderpref;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import fr.at.testsliderpref.utils.SeekBarPreference;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Call super :
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the activity's fragment :
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }


    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        private SeekBarPreference _seekBarPref;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.activity_settings);


            // Get widgets :
            _seekBarPref = (SeekBarPreference) this.findPreference("SEEKBAR_VALUE");

            // Set listener :
            getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

            // Set seekbar summary :
            int radius = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity()).getInt("SEEKBAR_VALUE", 50);
            _seekBarPref.setSummary(this.getString(R.string.settings_summary).replace("$1", ""+radius));
        }

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

            // Set seekbar summary :
            int radius = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity()).getInt("SEEKBAR_VALUE", 50);
            _seekBarPref.setSummary(this.getString(R.string.settings_summary).replace("$1", ""+radius));
        }
    }
}
```

layout > activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textview_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

menu > main.xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"/>

</menu>
```

xml > activity_settings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <fr.at.testsliderpref.utils.SeekBarPreference
            android:defaultValue="50"
            android:dialogMessage="@string/settings_dialog_message"
            android:key="SEEKBAR_VALUE"
            android:max="100"
            android:summary="@string/settings_summary"
            android:text="@string/settings_unit"
            android:title="@string/settings_title" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

values > strings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">TestSliderPref</string>
    <string name="textview_text">SeekBarPreference test</string>

    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="settings_dialog_message">Here comes a message</string>
    <string name="settings_summary">Current value is $1</string>
    <string name="settings_unit">Km</string>
    <string name="settings_title">Here comes the title</string>

</resources>
```

Don't forget to add your SettingsActivity to the manifest, and it should be OK.

Comment: Is this supposed to show the slider in a dialog, or right on the preferences page? The code looks like it uses a dialog, but when I implement it, the slider is on the preferences page.

Comment: Also, could you add a snippet of the setup XML showing the values that the class is looking for?

Comment: Hi. Yes, this pref is clickable and opens a popup. I added a XML snippet and a snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had left out the Summary value in the XML, but otherwise I had that part set up correctly. The slider is still displaying within a row of the Preferences list for me. The value is still saved and retrieved as expected. Strange...

Comment: I updated my answer with all the needed pieces of code. I just re-created a project from scratch and it is working. If you want I can send it to you, but you should be able to get it working with the above pieces of code.

Comment: @tim I am implementing your solution and I got the same result as arlomedia, I am getting the seekbar right in the preference item, not in the dialog and its not clickable.

Comment: how to store value in SharedPreferences  on click 'ok' in SettingsActivity

Comment: @arlomedia, I had the same problem. It turns out that I was just using <SeekBarPreference... which was not actually pointing to the SeekBarPreference class in my project but something else. I was able to fix my problem by doing <com.example.SeekBarPreference...

Comment: Hey!  In AndroidX, `onCreateDialogView()` does not exist.  How can I do this cool code and still maintain compatibility?

Answer (score 18):

If you already moved to **androidX** you can simply use     **androidx.preference.SeekBarPreference**. Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/components-and-attributes) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/SeekBarPreference)

Define it in XML like this:

```
<SeekBarPreference
        app:defaultValue="8"
        app:key="COUNT_SPEED"
        app:title="Fast count speed"
        />
```

[image]

**Note:** Now in Android Studio (my current version is 3.2.1) auto-suggestions doesn't work for androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen in prefs.xml, but don't worry inflating settings from xml with setPreferencesFromResource() works fine. All needed attributes names and component references you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/components-and-attributes).

Comment: And it does not show up in the Design screen either.  Thanks, you saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: Oh, this is great news!

Answer (score 16):

An easy way to achieve this is to add an empty preference to your preferences.xml which uses a layout including a seekbar.

In your preferences.xml add

```
<Preference android:layout="@layout/sliderlayout" />
```

under layouts add the sliderlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is good Slider Preference component - Android Slider Preference Library
[image]

https://github.com/jayschwa/AndroidSliderPreference

Comment: I just added this to my project. It stores the value as a float from 0-1, which I wanted, but might not be what you want. Also, it uses a separate layout file, which is less self-contained than solutions that build the layout from the class code.

Comment: Here's something that tripped me up for a while: this library saves the value as a float, and will crash whenever you run it if you had previously saved your value as an int. In this case, you would need to clear your previous value, or update your app to convert the value's type before running the preferences activity.

Answer (score 2):

One more implementation of this.
All Credit goes to Tim Autin.

I wanted to have the values displayed loaded from XML Arrays

It looks like this

[image: Seekbar setting loading items from XML]

Code - this now extends ListPreference

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SeekBarListPreference extends ListPreference implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private attributes :
    private static final String androidns = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private TextView mSplashText, mValueText;
    private Context mContext;

    private String mDialogMessage;
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    public SeekBarListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mContext = context;

        // Get string value for dialogMessage :
        int mDialogMessageId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(androidns, "dialogMessage", 0);
        if (mDialogMessageId == 0)
            mDialogMessage = attrs.getAttributeValue(androidns, "dialogMessage");
        else mDialogMessage = mContext.getString(mDialogMessageId);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // DialogPreference methods :
    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);

        mSplashText = new TextView(mContext);
        mSplashText.setPadding(30, 10, 30, 10);
        if (mDialogMessage != null)
            mSplashText.setText(mDialogMessage);
        layout.addView(mSplashText);

        mValueText = new TextView(mContext);
        mValueText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mValueText.setTextSize(32);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.addView(mValueText, params);

        mSeekBar = new SeekBar(mContext);
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        layout.addView(mSeekBar, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        setProgressBarValue();

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
        // do not call super
    }

    private void setProgressBarValue() {
        String mValue = null;
        if (shouldPersist()) {
            mValue = getValue();
        }

        final int max = this.getEntries().length - 1;

        mSeekBar.setMax(max);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(this.findIndexOfValue(mValue));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        setProgressBarValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek, int value, boolean fromTouch) {
        final CharSequence textToDisplay = getEntryFromValue(value);
        mValueText.setText(textToDisplay);
    }

    private CharSequence getEntryFromValue(int value) {
        CharSequence[] entries = getEntries();
        return value >= 0 && entries != null ? entries[value] : null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void showDialog(Bundle state) {
        super.showDialog(state);

        Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (shouldPersist()) {
            final int progressChoice = mSeekBar.getProgress();
            setValueIndex(progressChoice);
        }

        getDialog().dismiss();
    }
}
```

The usage in the preferences file is now

```
<com.yourfullpackage.SeekBarListPreference
        android:defaultValue="0"
        android:dialogMessage="@string/time_limit_pref"
        android:entries="@array/timeListArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/timeListValues"
        android:key="time"
        android:summary="Select time limit"
        android:title="Time"
        />
```

And the arrays

```
<string-array name="timeListArray">
    <item>10 Seconds</item>
    <item>30 Seconds</item>
    <item>1 Minute</item>
    <item>2 Minutes</item>
    <item>Unlimited</item>
</string-array>

<!--This is going to be in seconds-->
<string-array name="timeListValues">
    <item>10</item>
    <item>30</item>
    <item>60</item>
    <item>120</item>
    <item>0</item>
</string-array>
```

As a bonus if you already have ListPreferences, you don't need to add anything extra to display the summary as the current value. So this works just fine

```
    @Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    SetSummaryForPreferenceKey(key);
}

private void SetSummaryForPreferenceKey(String key) {
    Preference preference = findPreference(key);

    // This works with our new SeekBarPreference
    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
        ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) preference;
        listPref.setSummary(listPref.getEntry());
    }
}
```

Comment: how I can store value and than return via SharedPreference?

Answer (score 1):

I've made a slight improvement on the code provided in the answer by Tim. This simply makes live adjustments to the output value as the user moves the slider, rather than requiring the user to click the "Ok" button for the changes to be made.

This is useful for things like a Music Volume slider, where the user should be able to hear the adjustment in volume as it's being made.

If the user clicks "OK" the new value is maintained. If the user clicks "Cancel" then the original pre-adjustment value is restored.

Thanks and credit should go to Tim, I just added the extra onClick listener and pushed the value updating into the onChange listener.

```
package fr.atcm.carpooling.views.utils;

/* The following code was written by Matthew Wiggins 
 * and is released under the APACHE 2.0 license 
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Improvements :
 * - save the value on positive button click and/or seekbar change
 * - restore pre-adjustment value on negative button click
 */

import android.R;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SeekBarPreference extends DialogPreference implements
        SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnClickListener {
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private attributes :
    private static final String androidns = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private TextView mSplashText, mValueText;
    private Context mContext;

    private String mDialogMessage, mSuffix;
    private int mDefault, mMax, mValue, mOrig = 0;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor :
    public SeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;

        // Get string value for dialogMessage :
        int mDialogMessageId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(androidns,
                "dialogMessage", 0);
        if (mDialogMessageId == 0)
            mDialogMessage = attrs
                    .getAttributeValue(androidns, "dialogMessage");
        else
            mDialogMessage = mContext.getString(mDialogMessageId);

        // Get string value for suffix (text attribute in xml file) :
        int mSuffixId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(androidns, "text", 0);
        if (mSuffixId == 0)
            mSuffix = attrs.getAttributeValue(androidns, "text");
        else
            mSuffix = mContext.getString(mSuffixId);

        // Get default and max seekbar values :
        mDefault = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(androidns, "defaultValue", 0);
        mMax = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(androidns, "max", 100);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // DialogPreference methods :
    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);

        mSplashText = new TextView(mContext);
        mSplashText.setPadding(30, 10, 30, 10);
        if (mDialogMessage != null)
            mSplashText.setText(mDialogMessage);
        layout.addView(mSplashText);

        mValueText = new TextView(mContext);
        mValueText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mValueText.setTextSize(32);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.addView(mValueText, params);

        mSeekBar = new SeekBar(mContext);
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        layout.addView(mSeekBar, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        if (shouldPersist())
            mValue = getPersistedInt(mDefault);

        mSeekBar.setMax(mMax);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mValue);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        mSeekBar.setMax(mMax);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mValue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restore, Object defaultValue) {
        super.onSetInitialValue(restore, defaultValue);
        // Set adjustable value
        if (restore)
            mValue = shouldPersist() ? getPersistedInt(mDefault) : 0;
        else
            mValue = (Integer) defaultValue;
        // Set original pre-adjustment value
        mOrig = mValue;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // OnSeekBarChangeListener methods :
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek, int value, boolean fromTouch) {
        String t = String.valueOf(value);
        mValueText.setText(mSuffix == null ? t : t.concat(" " + mSuffix));

        if (shouldPersist()) {
            mValue = mSeekBar.getProgress();
            persistInt(mSeekBar.getProgress());
            callChangeListener(Integer.valueOf(mSeekBar.getProgress()));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek) {
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        mMax = max;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return mMax;
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        mValue = progress;
        if (mSeekBar != null)
            mSeekBar.setProgress(progress);
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return mValue;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Set the positive button listener and onClick action : 
    @Override
    public void showDialog(Bundle state) {

        super.showDialog(state);

        Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) getDialog())
                .getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        Button negativeButton = ((AlertDialog) getDialog())
                .getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(cListenPos);
        negativeButton.setOnClickListener(cListenNeg);
    }

    View.OnClickListener cListenPos = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (shouldPersist()) {
                mValue = mSeekBar.getProgress();
                mOrig = mSeekBar.getProgress();
                persistInt(mSeekBar.getProgress());
                callChangeListener(Integer.valueOf(mSeekBar.getProgress()));
            }
            ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).dismiss();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener cListenNeg = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (shouldPersist()) {
                mValue = mOrig;
                persistInt(mOrig);
                callChangeListener(Integer.valueOf(mOrig));
            }
            ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).dismiss();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {}

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: I just wonder how you suppose to catch slider bar live adjustments. Shall I implement OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener? But you wrote that OK button will persist final value.

Answer (score 1):

One small improvement of Tim's answer and its derivates:

```
protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
    super.onBindDialogView(v);
    mSeekBar.setMax(mMax);
    mSeekBar.setProgress(mValue);
    String t = String.valueOf(mValue);
    mValueText.setText(mSuffix == null ? t : t.concat(" " + mSuffix));
}
```

It will populate current value at start which is otherwise empty until you actually slide the slider.