# Is there a way to add a seekbar to my actual preference screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I keep seeing the tutorial on adding your own seekbar preference, but its not in my actual prefs.xml. Is there any way to have one in my main prefs screen or will I have to separate it.

Comment: Kirk Baucom has recently published the code to do exactly that: [Android SeekBar preference](http://robobunny.com/wp/2011/08/13/android-seekbar-preference/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There seem to be 2 slider preferences by Google -

- [SeekBarPreference](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/preference/SeekBarPreference.java) - inline
- [SeekBarDialogPreference](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/preference/SeekBarDialogPreference.java) - dialog based

but I am not sure when they will be available.

You could use a custom *inline* [SeekBarPreference](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/MyPrefs) by me (see the 2 sliders at the bottom):

[image: screenshot]

My code is quite simple -

[SeekBarPreference.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/MyPrefs/src/de/afarber/myprefs/SeekBarPreference.java):

```
public class SeekBarPreference extends Preference implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private int mProgress;

    public SeekBarPreference(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public SeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_seekbar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mProgress);
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (!fromUser)
            return;

        setValue(progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // not used
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // not used
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
        setValue(restoreValue ? getPersistedInt(mProgress) : (Integer) defaultValue);
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        if (shouldPersist()) {
            persistInt(value);
        }

        if (value != mProgress) {
            mProgress = value;
            notifyChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return a.getInt(index, 0);
    }
}
```

And [preference_seekbar.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/MyPrefs/res/layout/preference_seekbar.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For some reason, the `notifyChanged()` in the `setValue()` function does not result in my `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.onPreferenceChange()` from being called. Instead, I had to replace `notifyChanged()` with `callChangeListener(value)` for it to get called. P.S. I register the callback with `preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener()`.