# How to set a slider in PreferenceScreen of Android?

Tags: android

I know there are checkBoxPreference, ListPreference and EditTextPreference controls in PreferenceScreen.

Is there a slider control in PreferenceScreen which I can set max value and min value ,and select any value between max and min value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Aniqroid](https://code.google.com/p/aniqroid/) to use seek bar in Preference activity.

SeekBarPreference [Documentation](http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/com/sileria/android/view/SeekBarPreference.html) and [Listener](http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/com/sileria/android/event/PrefsSeekBarListener.html).

Comment: Why use a toolkit when you can just code it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974193/slider-on-my-preferencescreen?answertab=oldest#tab-top) useful. Your basically extending CheckBoxPreference, ListPreference, and EditTextPreference through XML instead of Java *(the `extends` keyword)*.