# SharedPreferences.getAll does not return custom preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to get a list of all the preferences for my Android application, doing it this way from the `onCreate()` method of my `PreferenceActivity` class:

```
PreferenceManager prefManager = getPreferenceManager();

for (String key : prefManager.getSharedPreferences().getAll().keySet())
{
    Log.i("___", key);
}
```

I'm getting all the preferences but one, which is a custom preference (basically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14326926/2821510) with some small modifications).
Why isn't the custom preference in the list returned by `getAll()`? I'm just completely lost here, does the function only return Android's built-in preferences for any reason? Is there any way to actually get all the preferences?

---

Edit:

After I interact with the custom preference, `getAll()` does return it, but why is that the case, when I get the others without any interaction? Is it possible to get all the preferences without first interacting with them?

---

### Custom preference

```
/* The following code was originally written by Matthew Wiggins
 * and is released under the APACHE 2.0 license 
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Improvements :
 * - save the value on positive button click, not on seekbar change
 * - handle @string/... values in xml file
 * 
 * With further modifications by Trinidad Sibajas
 */


package com.SkiesOpened.SimplyGrass;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class NumberSliderPreference extends DialogPreference implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnClickListener
{
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private attributes :

    // private static final String androidns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private TextView mSplashText,mValueText;
    private Context mContext;

    private String mDialogMessage;
    private int mDefault, mMax, mValue = 0;
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor :
    public NumberSliderPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs); 


        mContext = context;


        // Set the initial values:
        TypedArray attrArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.NumberSliderPreferenceAttributes);

        mDialogMessage = attrArray.getString(R.styleable.NumberSliderPreferenceAttributes_android_dialogMessage);
        mDefault       = attrArray.getInt   (R.styleable.NumberSliderPreferenceAttributes_android_defaultValue, 0);
        mMax           = attrArray.getInt   (R.styleable.NumberSliderPreferenceAttributes_android_max,          0);

        attrArray.recycle();
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------








    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // DialogPreference methods :
    @Override 
    protected View onCreateDialogView()
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(6,6,6,6);

        mSplashText = new TextView(mContext);
        mSplashText.setPadding(30, 10, 30, 10);
        if (mDialogMessage != null)
            mSplashText.setText(mDialogMessage);
        layout.addView(mSplashText);

        mValueText = new TextView(mContext);
        mValueText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mValueText.setTextSize(32);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.addView(mValueText, params);
        setValueText(mValue);

        mSeekBar = new SeekBar(mContext);
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        layout.addView(mSeekBar, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        if (shouldPersist())
            mValue = getPersistedInt(mDefault);

        mSeekBar.setMax(mMax);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mValue);

        return layout;
    }








    @Override 
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v)
    {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        mSeekBar.setMax(mMax);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mValue);
    }








    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restore, Object defaultValue)  
    {
        super.onSetInitialValue(restore, defaultValue);

        if (restore) 
            mValue = shouldPersist() ? getPersistedInt(mDefault) : 0;
        else 
            mValue = (Integer)defaultValue;
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------








    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // OnSeekBarChangeListener methods :
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
    {
        setValueText(progress);
    }








    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek)
    {
    }








    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek)
    {
    }








    public void setMax(int max)
    {
        mMax = max;
    }








    public int getMax()
    {
        return mMax;
    }








    public void setProgress(int progress)
    { 
        mValue = progress;

        if (mSeekBar != null)
            mSeekBar.setProgress(progress); 
    }








    public int getProgress()
    {
        return mValue;
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------








    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Set the positive button listener and onClick action : 
    @Override
    public void showDialog(Bundle state)
    {
        super.showDialog(state);

        Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog)getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }








    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (shouldPersist())
        {
            mValue = mSeekBar.getProgress();
            persistInt(mSeekBar.getProgress());
            callChangeListener(Integer.valueOf(mSeekBar.getProgress()));
        }

        ((AlertDialog)getDialog()).dismiss();
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------








    void setValueText(int value)
    {
        mValueText.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }
}
```

### PreferenceActivity

```
package com.SkiesOpened.SimplyGrass;

import android.R.integer;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;


public class SimplyGrassSettings extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    private CheckBoxPreference changeWindPreference;
    private Preference fixedWindAnglePreference;
    private Preference fixedWindStrengthPreference;








    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
    {
        // Enable/disable the fixed wind angle and strength options as needed:
        if (key.equals("changeWind"))
        {
            checkChangeWindPreferenceState();
        }


        // Set the summary:
        setPreferenceSummary(key);
    }








    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);


        PreferenceManager prefManager = getPreferenceManager();

        prefManager.setSharedPreferencesName(SimplyGrass.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.wallpaper_settings);
        prefManager.getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.wallpaper_settings, false);


        changeWindPreference = (CheckBoxPreference)prefManager.findPreference("changeWind");
        fixedWindAnglePreference = prefManager.findPreference("fixedWindAngle");
        fixedWindStrengthPreference = prefManager.findPreference("fixedWindStrength");

        checkChangeWindPreferenceState();


        for (String key : prefManager.getSharedPreferences().getAll().keySet())
        {
            Log.i("_________", key);
            setPreferenceSummary(key);
        }
    }








    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }








    void checkChangeWindPreferenceState()
    {
        boolean enableFixedPrefs = ! changeWindPreference.isChecked();

        fixedWindAnglePreference.setEnabled(enableFixedPrefs);
        fixedWindStrengthPreference.setEnabled(enableFixedPrefs);
    }








    void setPreferenceSummary(String key)
    {
        Preference pref = findPreference(key);

        if (pref instanceof NumberSliderPreference)
            pref.setSummary(Integer.toString(((NumberSliderPreference)pref).getProgress()));
        else if (pref instanceof ListPreference)
            pref.setSummary(((ListPreference)pref).getEntry());
    }
}
```

### XML preferences file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="wallpaper_settings"
    android:title="@string/wallpaper_settings" >

    <!-- Ad Placeholder -->
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/basicCategoryTitle">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="doubleTap"
            android:summary="@string/doubleTapSummary"
            android:title="@string/doubleTapTitle"
        />
        <ListPreference
            android:key="maxFPS"
            android:title="@string/maxFPSTitle"
            android:defaultValue="@string/maxFPSDefault"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/maxFPSTitle"
            android:entries="@array/maxFPSEntries"
            android:entryValues="@array/maxFPSValues"
        />
    </PreferenceCategory>


    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/advancedCategoryTitle">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="changeWind"
            android:title="@string/changeWindTitle"
            android:summary="@string/changeWindSummary"
            android:defaultValue="true"
        />
        <ListPreference
            android:key="fixedWindAngle"
            android:title="@string/fixedWindAngleTitle"
            android:defaultValue="@string/fixedWindAngleDefault"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/fixedWindAngleTitle"
            android:entries="@array/fixedWindAngleEntries"
            android:entryValues="@array/fixedWindAngleValues"
        />
        <com.SkiesOpened.SimplyGrass.NumberSliderPreference
            android:key="fixedWindStrength"
            android:title="@string/fixedWindStrengthTitle"
            android:dialogMessage="Bleh bleh bleh"
            android:defaultValue="@integer/fixedWindStrengthDefault"
            android:max="100"
        />
        <ListPreference
            android:key="particlesEmissionRate"
            android:title="@string/particlesEmissionRateTitle"
            android:defaultValue="@string/particlesEmissionRateDefault"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/particlesEmissionRateTitle"
            android:entries="@array/particlesEmissionRateEntries"
            android:entryValues="@array/particlesEmissionRateValues"
        />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

### Strings XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Simply Grass</string>
    <string name="app_description"></string>


    <string name="wallpaper_settings">Simply Grass settings</string>

    <string name="basicCategoryTitle">Basic preferences</string>
    <string name="advancedCategoryTitle">Advanced preferences</string>


    <string name="doubleTapTitle">Double tap for settings</string>
    <string name="doubleTapSummary">Double tap anywhere on the home screen to open this settings menu.</string>


    <string name="maxFPSTitle">Limit FPS</string>
    <string-array name="maxFPSEntries">
        <item>15\n(lowest battery usage)</item>
        <item>30</item>
        <item>45</item>
        <item>No limit</item>
    </string-array>


    <string name="changeWindTitle">Change wind over time</string>
    <string name="changeWindSummary">Makes the wind direction and strength change over time.</string>


    <string name="fixedWindAngleTitle">Fixed wind direction</string>
    <string-array name="fixedWindAngleEntries">
        <item>North</item>
        <item>Northeast</item>
        <item>East</item>
        <item>Southeast</item>
        <item>South</item>
        <item>Southwest</item>
        <item>West</item>
        <item>Northwest</item>
    </string-array>


    <string name="fixedWindStrengthTitle">Fixed wind strength</string>


    <string name="particlesEmissionRateTitle">Particles amount</string>
    <string-array name="particlesEmissionRateEntries">
        <item>No particles\n(lowest battery usage)</item>
        <item>Low</item>
        <item>Medium</item>
        <item>High</item>
        <item>Very high</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

### Values XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="maxFPSDefault">0</string>
    <string-array name="maxFPSValues">
        <item>15</item>
        <item>30</item>
        <item>45</item>
        <item>0</item>
    </string-array>


    <integer name="fixedWindStrengthDefault">30</integer>


    <string-array name="fixedWindAngleValues">
        <item>90</item>
        <item>45</item>
        <item>0</item>
        <item>-45</item>
        <item>-90</item>
        <item>-135</item>
        <item>180</item>
        <item>135</item>
    </string-array>


    <string name="fixedWindAngleDefault">45</string>


    <string name="particlesEmissionRateDefault">2</string>
    <string-array name="particlesEmissionRateValues">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

### Custom preference attributes XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="NumberSliderPreferenceAttributes">
        <attr name="android:title"/>
        <attr name="android:summary"/>
        <attr name="android:dialogMessage"/>
        <attr name="android:defaultValue"/>
        <attr name="android:max"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Your custom `Preference` is UI; `SharedPreferences` is the data model. Have you actually shown a `PreferenceScreen` containing your custom `Preference`, and have you actually interacted with your custom `Preference`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I showed the screen, but I didn't interact with the custom preference. I've just tried the latter, and now I get it. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code, but it seems that the others are getting created with a default value, while that one is not.

Comment: @DanielNugent I've just added all the relevant code, in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't been able to find out why `SharedPreferences.getAll()` does not return my custom preference, so at the end I'm using an ugly workaround that is working so far (from [here](http://www.codeitive.com/0xygggPqWq/sharedpreferencesgetall-does-not-have-preference-keys-that-are-false-how-to-retrieve-all-keys.html)):

```
final ListAdapter adapter = getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter();

for (int i = 0;  i < adapter.getCount();  i++)
{
    Object obj = adapter.getItem(i);

    if (obj instanceof Preference)
    {
        // Do stuff here with the preference.

        // If you need the key, get it but check for null before using it:
        String key = ((Preference)obj).getKey();

        if (key != null)
        {
            // Do stuff with the key.
        }
    } 
}
```