# Custom NumberPickerPreference - how to set the NumberPicker value?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-dialog, numberpicker

I have prepared [a simple test case](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q22/MyPrefs) for my problem at GitHub.

I have extended a [DialogPreference](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/preference/DialogPreference.java) to a custom [NumberPickerPreference](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q22/MyPrefs/src/de/afarber/myprefs/NumberPickerPreference.java) - and it works well: displays a `NumberPicker` in a dialog and saves integer value when the dialog is closed.

My problem is that the saved integer value is never used to set the `NumberPicker` - when the dialog opened:

[image: screenshot]

In the above screenshot you can see (in the summary field at the bottom) that the saved integer value is **14** (and I see that value being passed to `mPicker.setValue(mNumber)` call in debugger) - but the `NumberPicker` is still scrolled to **1**.

Here is the problematic [NumberPickerPreference.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q22/MyPrefs/src/de/afarber/myprefs/NumberPickerPreference.java):

```
public class NumberPickerPreference extends DialogPreference implements OnValueChangeListener {
    private NumberPicker mPicker;
    private Integer mNumber = 0;
    private Integer mPickerValue = 0; // keeps picker value before dialog closes

    public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_picker);
        setPositiveButtonText(android.R.string.ok);
        setNegativeButtonText(android.R.string.cancel);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view);
        mPicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.picker);
        mPicker.setValue(mNumber);
        mPicker.setMinValue(1);
        mPicker.setMaxValue(100);
        mPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        mPickerValue = newVal;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        if (positiveResult) {
            setValue(mPickerValue);
        }
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
        setValue(restoreValue ? getPersistedInt(mNumber) : (Integer) defaultValue);
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        if (shouldPersist()) {
            persistInt(value);
        }

        if (value != mNumber) {
            mNumber = value;
            notifyChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return a.getInt(index, 0);
    }
}
```

And here is the layout file [preference_picker.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q22/MyPrefs/res/layout/preference_picker.xml):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls" >

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</ScrollView>
```

Does anybody please know, what is missing here?

Initially I thought, that adding `onGetDefaultValue` method would help - like in my other question ([Custom inline SeekBarPreference - how to set SeekBar progress on the 1st run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170384/custom-inline-seekbarpreference-how-to-set-seekbar-progress-on-the-1st-run)) - but it hasn't.

Comment: Try saving/restoring the instance state as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#CustomSaveState

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I had to apply 2 fixes to my custom preference:

1. [mPicker.setValue()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setValue%28int%29) should be called **after** `setMinValue()` and `setMaxValue()` have been called.
2. `mPicker.clearFocus()` should be called before reading its value - as workaround for situations when user edits the value in the `TextEdit` and then clicks OK button in the `Dialog`:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my fixed source code (layout file is not needed anymore) -

[NumberPickerPreference.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/MyPrefs/src/de/afarber/myprefs/NumberPickerPreference.java):

```
public class NumberPickerPreference extends DialogPreference {
    private NumberPicker mPicker;
    private int mNumber = 0;

    public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setPositiveButtonText(android.R.string.ok);
        setNegativeButtonText(android.R.string.cancel);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        mPicker = new NumberPicker(getContext());
        mPicker.setMinValue(1);
        mPicker.setMaxValue(100);
        // should be called after setMinValue and setMaxValue
        mPicker.setValue(mNumber);
        return mPicker;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        if (positiveResult) {
            // needed when user edits the text field and clicks OK
            mPicker.clearFocus();
            setValue(mPicker.getValue());
        }
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
        setValue(restoreValue ? getPersistedInt(mNumber) : (Integer) defaultValue);
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        if (shouldPersist()) {
            persistInt(value);
        }

        if (value != mNumber) {
            mNumber = value;
            notifyChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return a.getInt(index, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I did not figure out why `mPicker.setValue()` in `onBindDialogView()` doesn't change the NumberPicker to the given value. However, to fix your problem, you can use `setOnPreferenceClickListener` and make a call to `mPicker.setValue( mNumber );`.

Truth be told, I'm not sure if this is a workaround or if this is how it is supposed to be.